# problems with developing Telegram bot in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

I am developing a bot for Telegram in Python with zero knowledge of the language, but I know swift very well and I try to follow it, but it doesn’t work.
I'm trying to make a logical expression so that when the message "Economy" the line "if message.text == 'Economy':" works, but it gives an error that I can't understand for several hours

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

 

keyboard1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
keyboard1.row('Группа ОБ20-1', 'Группа ОБ20-2', 'Группа ОБ20-3', 'Группа ОБ20-4')


keyboard2 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
keyboard2.row('Экономика', 'Астрология')









@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, выбери свою группу', reply_markup = keyboard1)



    







if message.text == 'Экономика':

  @bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
        def send_text(message):

    if message.text == 'Группа ОБ20-1':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '''9:00 - 10:30: История мировых цивилизаций (Зал: №3/6, Лектор: Прохоров Андрей Валерьевич) 
            \n10:40 - 12:10: История мировых цивилизаций (Зал: №3/6, Лектор: Прохоров Андрей Валерьевич) 
            \n12:20 - 13:50: - 
            \n14:00 - 15:30 - ''')

    elif message.text == 'Группа ОБ20-2':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '''9:00 - 10:30: История мировых цивилизаций (Зал: №3/6, Лектор: Прохоров Андрей Валерьевич) 
            \n10:40 - 12:10: -  
            \n12:20 - 13:50: Информационные технологии в управлении (Зал: -, Лектор: Журавлев Игорь Владимирович)''')

    elif message.text == 'Группа ОБ20-3':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '''9:00 - 10:30: История мировых цивилизаций (Зал: №3/6, Лектор: Прохоров Андрей Валерьевич) 
            \n10:40 - 12:10: Логика. Практические занятия (Зал: -, Лектор: Ковылин Юрий Алексеевич)  
            \n12:20 - 13:50: Информационные технологии в управлении. Лаб.Занятия (Зал: -, Лектор: Ващура Ирина Кириллсана)''')

    elif message.text == 'Группа ОБ20-4':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '''9:00 - 10:30: История мировых цивилизаций (Зал: №3/6, Лектор: Прохоров Андрей Валерьевич) 
            \n10:40 - 12:10: Введение в профессиональную деятельность. Практика (Зал: -, Лектор: Борисенков Алексей Александрович)  
            
            \n12:20 - 13:50: Логика. Практические занятия (Зал: -, Лектор: Борисенков Алексей Александрович)''')

    



bot.polling()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message suggests that the cause of the problem is due to 'wrong indentation'.

The problem can be solved by adding indentation to all the mis-aligned statements.

**Note on indetation used by Python:**

Python does not use curly-braces for enclosing code blocks. It depends on indentations (Either a tab or 4 blank spaces) to know the boundaries of code blocks.

Indents in Python are like the curly braces of Swift programming language.

**For example, Suppose that a function is Swift is like this:**

```
func my_function(_ s1: String, _ s2: String) -> Bool {
    if (s1 == s2) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

**The same function can be written in Python line this:**

```
def my_function (s1, s2):
    
    if (s1 == s2):
        return True
        
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an IndentationError; your Python indentation syntax is simply wonky (mixing and matching 0, 2, 6 and 4 spaces).

Syntax-wise, you're likely looking for something like the following, but do note that I have removed the `if message.text == 'Экономика':` bit, since it doesn't make sense being outside of a function (there is no `message` to be inspected!), nor does trying to register a bot reply handler in an `if` block.

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("token")


keyboard1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
keyboard1.row("Группа ОБ20-1", "Группа ОБ20-2", "Группа ОБ20-3", "Группа ОБ20-4")


keyboard2 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
keyboard2.row("Экономика", "Астрология")


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id, "Привет, выбери свою группу", reply_markup=keyboard1
    )


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text == "Группа ОБ20-1":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, """1...""")
    elif message.text == "Группа ОБ20-2":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, """2...""")
    elif message.text == "Группа ОБ20-3":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, """3...""")
    elif message.text == "Группа ОБ20-4":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, """4...""")


bot.polling()
```